# Function Running Multiple Times in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have created a function which makes an ajax request to a PHP file and then adds a product to the basket. This function works as it should on the first click, but on each subsequent click it runs the function again. So for example, on the 2nd click it runs the function twice, on the 3rd click it runs it three times and so on... The problem is reset when the page is refreshed...

Here's the on click code:

```
    $("#add_123456").click(function () {  
      $("#add_123456").addClass('added');          
      var quantity = $("#qty_123456").val();
      $('#basket_1').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        basket_add("feqf73nbdw7","123456","XYZ123","1","0.1","19.23");            
      });      
    });
```

Here's the function:

```
    function basket_add(cartID, productID, code, quantity, weight, price) {  
      var item_add = {"Cart_ID": cartID, 
                      "Product_ID" : productID,
                      "Code" : code,
                      "Qty" : quantity,
                      "Weight" : weight,
                      "Price" : price
                      };            
      $("#basketpop").animate({top: "40px"}, 200);    
      $.ajax({
        url:  '/templates/new/includes/ajax/add_to_basket.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: item_add,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html){
          $('.basket_content').empty().append(html);
          $('.basket_content').css("height", "auto");
          var item_add = null;
        }
      });
      return false;          
    };
```

Don't think the issue is with the PHP file that is being called.

Cheers

Comment: post your html code, and the html returned by the php page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the `#add_123456` button is a `submit` button, the problem is because you are adding a new `submit()` handler to the form on each click of the button. Instead you only need to add the submit handler once and raise the event on the form on button click. Try this:

```
$('#basket_1').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    basket_add("feqf73nbdw7","123456","XYZ123","1","0.1","19.23");            
});  

$("#add_123456").click(function () {  
    $("#add_123456").addClass('added');          
    var quantity = $("#qty_123456").val();
    $('#basket_1').submit();
});
```

If you are only submitting via AJAX though, you can remove the need to submit the form at all, like this:

```
$("#add_123456").click(function () {  
    $("#add_123456").addClass('added');          
    var quantity = $("#qty_123456").val();
    basket_add("feqf73nbdw7","123456","XYZ123","1","0.1","19.23");            
});
```

Comment: hi thanks for your response, i've tried this and a different problem occurs, where the function is being run twice, every time

Comment: your second option unfortunately doesn't work, the page just refreshes

Comment: @DanielKilburn You need to remove the form for the second option to work correctly, or make the submit button just a plain button or a link.

Answer (score 2):

Because every time you click the `#add_123456`, the code `$('#basket_1').submit(function (event) {...})` will be run, which will add a callback function to `$('#basket_1').submit`, you may want to bind the callback first, and trigger `submit` when `click`.

Something like:

```
   $('#basket_1').submit(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      basket_add("feqf73nbdw7","123456","XYZ123","1","0.1","19.23");            
   });  

   $("#add_123456").click(function () {  
      $("#add_123456").addClass('added');          
      var quantity = $("#qty_123456").val(); 
      $('#basket_1').trigger('submit');   
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be created by the submit listener. A new one will be appended at every click.
Maybe you should have separate your submit listerer doing something like that:

```
 $("#add_123456").click(function () {  
  $("#add_123456").addClass('added');          
  var quantity = $("#qty_123456").val();

});

 $('#basket_1').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    basket_add("feqf73nbdw7","123456","XYZ123","1","0.1","19.23");            
  });
```

Another solution is to unbind your listener before binding:

```
$("#add_123456").click(function () {  
  $("#add_123456").addClass('added');          
  var quantity = $("#qty_123456").val();
  $('#basket_1').unbind( 'submit' ).bind( 'submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    basket_add("feqf73nbdw7","123456","XYZ123","1","0.1","19.23");            
  });      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching another event handler every time the button is clicked.
Either attach the onsubmit handler outside of the onclick handler, or use

```
  $('#basket_1').off('submit').on('submit',(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    basket_add("feqf73nbdw7","123456","XYZ123","1","0.1","19.23");            
  });
```